# unable to locate aws credential file from php

Tags: php, unix, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

In PHP file  below aws cli s3 copy  command  is not working  its giving an error credentials not found.

But when it's executed in unix command line it's working.

Have the aws credentials in the home directory and gave read access to other users

```
~/.aws
total 8
-rw------- 1 root root  10 Aug 31 14:47 config
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 349 Aug 31 14:50 credentials

exec("aws s3 cp $s3_location $local_dest")
```

Comment: Can you test without `$s3_location` and `$local_dest` (write the full path) ?

Answer (score 0):

When using php, you should maybe use the php sdk.

You can check [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/credentials.html) for the different and best methods to get credentials

Example - If you have your `credentials` file as something like

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = YOUR_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
aws_secret_access_key = YOUR_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
```

and your `config` file contains region like

```
[default]
region=us-east-1
```

you can create a S3 client as simple as

```
<?php

use Aws\S3\S3Client;

// Instantiate a client with the credentials from the project1 profile
$s3Client = S3Client::factory();
```

If you do not have full configuration set or want to change the region e.g.

```
// Instantiate a client with the credentials from the project1 profile
$s3Client = S3Client::factory(array(
    'region'  => 'us-west-2',
));
```

To copy an object, you can look at the [copy-object method](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-s3-2006-03-01.html#copyobject)

```
use Aws\S3\S3Client;

$sourceBucket = '*** Your Source Bucket Name ***';
$sourceKeyname = '*** Your Source Object Key ***';
$targetBucket = '*** Your Target Bucket Name ***';
$targetKeyname = '*** Your Target Key Name ***';        

// Instantiate the client.
$s3 = S3Client::factory();

// Copy an object.
$s3->copyObject(array(
    'Bucket'     => $targetBucket,
    'Key'        => $targetKeyname,
    'CopySource' => "{$sourceBucket}/{$sourceKeyname}",
));
```

Note : you dont need to give access to other on your credential file, keep it as

```
~/.aws
total 8
-rw------- 1 root root  10 Aug 31 14:47 config
-rw------- 1 root root 349 Aug 31 14:50 credentials
```